Hide False MSAL 4.64.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.8 logging messages
In a .NET 8 API project, I'm logging via Serilog to a Application Insights. With every request, I see a lot of False MSAL 4.64.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.8 messages which I want to hide in traces.
In my service, I'm using ITokenAcquisition to gather a token for the backend service.
accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new[] { _configuration["PasApi:ScopeForAccessToken"] });

In appsettings.json, I've added Logging configuration to exclude specific logging from packages. Also tried with Microsoft.Identity.
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
     "Default": "Information",
     "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
     "MSAL.NetCore": "Warning"
  }
}

Also tried to add a exclude filtering in the serilog configuration, without any success.
"Serilog": {
  "MinimumLevel": {
    "Default": "Information",
    "Override": {
      "Microsoft": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
      "System": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "ApplicationInsights",
    "Args": { 
       "telemetryConverter": "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter, Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
     }
  }
  ],
  "Filter": [
    {
      "Name": "ByExcluding",
      "Args": {
         "expression": "Contains(@MessageTemplate, 'False MSAL')"
      }
    }
  ]
},

How can I avoid this?

Example MessageTemplate
False MSAL 4.64.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.8 Microsoft Windows 10.0.19045 [2024-09-17 09:57:46Z - 4671fb35-5f88-41a6-95f0-6b53f07cf66f] TokenEndpoint: ****
Program.cs
builder.Host.UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) => loggerConfiguration.ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration));
builder.Services.AddAadRegistration(Configuration);

public static IServiceCollection AddAadRegistration(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
  services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(configuration.GetSection(AppSettings.AZUREAD))
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

  services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
  {
      options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = @"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress";
  });

  var origins = new List<string>();
  configuration.Bind(AppSettings.CORS_MAIN, origins);

  services.AddCors(options =>
  {
      options.AddPolicy(name: Policies.CORS_MAIN,
        builder => builder.WithOrigins(origins.ToArray())
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader());
  });

  return services;
}

Packages
Azure.Identity v1.12.0
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer v8.0.8
Microsoft.Identity.Client 4.64.0
Microsoft.Identity.Web 3.1.0
Serilog.AspNetCore 8.0.2
Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights 4.0.0

The image doesn't show the message template. That's either the message itself, or a flattened view of the parameters. Can you expand one of the entries to see what it contains? BTW how do you export the data to AppInsights? Where do you apply the filter?

@PanagiotisKanavos I've edited my question and added the Serilog config

@NiAu - Are u getting other logs correctly?

@Harshitha the HTTP GET is as expected

@NiAu
I've tried your code and didn't get any False MSAL 4.64.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.8 messages in my traces. can you provide the code you used (Program.cs, csproj, and the logging configuration) so that it will be easier to identify the issue.

if possible provide your github repo

@SirraSneha it's in a private company repo, but what do you require to get some more information?

@NiAu Provide the dependencies in your .csproj file related to logging and MSAL.

@NiAu if the problem is real you won't have trouble producing a minimal example. The real problem is that you keep trying to filter the wrong thing and the wrong data. The MesssageTemplate doesn't contain what you assume. The relevant part in Sirra Sneha's answer is .MinimumLevel.Override("MSAL.NetCore", LogEventLevel.Warning), which blocks messages sent from MSAL.NetCore. The answer ignores the JSON settings too.  It's a good idea to configure logging in code if you aren't certain about the JSON syntax. Personally I rarely use JSON settings for Serilog

@SirraSneha I've added extra information such as program config and package versions

@PanagiotisKanavos I get the difference between JSON config & code for .MinimumLevel.Override("MSAL.NetCore", LogEventLevel.Warning), but not why it shouldn't work in JSON.

I created a sample ASP .NET 8 API application, successfully configured Application Insights without any issues.
I've installed the below packages in my application
Serilog.AspNetCore
Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore
Microsoft.Identity.Client

my appsettings.json:
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
      "MSAL.NetCore": "Warning" 
    }
  },
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "<your-connectionstring>"
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Information",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
        "MSAL.NetCore": "Warning" 
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "ApplicationInsights",
        "Args": {
          "telemetryConverter": "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter, Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Console"
      }
    ],
    "Filter": [
      {
        "Name": "ByExcluding",
        "Args": {
          "expression": "Contains(@MessageTemplate, 'False MSAL')"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "AzureAd": {
    "ClientId": "<client-id>",
    "ClientSecret": "<client-secret>",
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "TenantId": "<tenant-id>"
  }
}

I've reffered this  Github doc  and included the below code in my program.cs for Serilog logging.
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Information()
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore", LogEventLevel.Warning)
    .MinimumLevel.Override("MSAL.NetCore", LogEventLevel.Warning)
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(new TelemetryConfiguration { ConnectionString = connectionString }, TelemetryConverter.Traces)
    .Filter.ByExcluding(e => e.MessageTemplate.Text.Contains("MSAL"))
    .CreateLogger();

program.cs :
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Events;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

string connectionString = builder.Configuration["ApplicationInsights:ConnectionString"];
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(options =>
{
    options.ConnectionString = connectionString;
});

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Information()
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore", LogEventLevel.Warning)
    .MinimumLevel.Override("MSAL.NetCore", LogEventLevel.Warning)
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(new TelemetryConfiguration { ConnectionString = connectionString }, TelemetryConverter.Traces)
    .Filter.ByExcluding(e => e.MessageTemplate.Text.Contains(" Final MSAL"))
    .CreateLogger();
builder.Host.UseSerilog();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfidentialClientApplication>(sp =>
{
    return ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(builder.Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"])        .WithClientSecret(builder.Configuration["AzureAd:ClientSecret"])
        .WithAuthority(new Uri($"{builder.Configuration["AzureAd:Instance"]}{builder.Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]}"))      .WithLogging((Microsoft.Identity.Client.LogLevel level, string message, bool containsPii) =>
        {
            if (!containsPii && level >= Microsoft.Identity.Client.LogLevel.Warning)
            {
                Log.Information(message);
            }
        }, Microsoft.Identity.Client.LogLevel.Warning, enablePiiLogging: false)
        .Build();
});
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();

Here's the Output:


Refer this SO answer by @ Harshitha.

What in all this code actually solves the problem? It works because it ignores the Serilog settings completely and configures a filter in code with MinimumLevel.Override("MSAL.NetCore", LogEventLevel.Warning). The other filter, Filter.ByExcluding(e => e.MessageTemplate.Text.Contains(" Final MSAL")) is the same as the original and does nothing at all. The template doesn't contain the string Final MSAL to begin with

@Panagiotis Kanavos Thank you for your feedback. I made changes to ensure the Serilog configuration in
Program.cs
takes effect. The programmatic configuration in code overrides the settings in
appsettings.json
, ensuring everything works as expected

The answer's code doesn't override the settings. There's no .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration) so the settings are never loaded. The only relevant code is the line .MinimumLevel.Override("MSAL.NetCore", LogEventLevel.Warning). The filter .Filter.ByExcluding(e => e.MessageTemplate.Text.Contains(" Final MSAL")) has no effect - it's the same filter the OP used, the one that doesn't work

@Panagiotis Kanavos I will review the implementation to ensure the configuration is correctly applied and will make adjustments accordingly. Thank you for your feedback.

@SirraSneha thanks for the answer, but I assume that the ITokenAcquisition is pushing all those messages.

will update you after trying out your code.
